# Linear dependences over the field with two elements

Tags: code-golf, abstract-algebra, linear-algebra

The \$d\$-dimensional vector space \$\mathbb{F}_2^d\$ over the field with two elements \$\mathbb{F}_2\$ is the set of vectors of \$d\$ bits. Addition of vectors is bitwise xor. A linear dependence is a set of vectors whose total (xor them all together) is \$0\$. Every set of \$d+1\$ vectors in \$\mathbb{F}_2^d\$ contains a linear dependence. We will represent the elements of \$\mathbb{F}_2^d\$ as the integers \$0\$ through \$2^{d}-1\$ using the binary expansion.

### Task

Input: a positive integer \$d\$ and a list of \$d+1\$ positive integers between \$1\$ and \$2^{d}-1\$. You may assume that the list is sorted and you may assume that the entries are distinct.

Output: A nonempty subset of the \$d+1\$ numbers whose bitwise xor is zero.

### Scoring:

This is code golf so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Examples:

```
Input: (3, [1,3,4,7])
Output: [3, 4, 7]
```

In binary, these are 001, 011, 100, and 111. We see that 100 xor 011 xor 111 = 000. In this case this is the only solution, so we must output [3, 4, 7].

### Test cases:

```
Input: (3, [1,3,4,7])
Output: [3, 4, 7]

Input: (4, [1, 2, 6, 10, 30])
Output: Behavior undetermined because 30 > 15 = 2^4 - 1.

Input: (5, [3, 5, 6, 9, 14])
Output: [3, 5, 6]

Input: (5, [4, 8, 10, 12, 14])
Output: [4, 8, 12] or [4, 10, 14], or [8, 10, 12, 14].

Input: (6, [4, 15, 17, 21, 49, 51, 57])
Output: [4, 17, 21]

Input: (6, [1, 7, 8, 15, 39, 55, 57]) 
Output: [7, 8, 15] or [1, 15, 55, 57] or [1, 7, 8, 55, 57]

Input: (6, [13, 14, 24, 33, 35, 36, 63]) 
Output: [13, 14, 24, 36, 63]

Input: (6, [10, 11, 25, 28, 40, 59, 62])
Output: [10, 25, 40, 59] or [10, 28, 40, 62], or [25, 28, 59, 62]

Input: (6, [1, 3, 5, 11, 19, 32, 63])
Output: [1, 3, 5, 11, 19, 32, 63]
```

Comment: May we return all solutions?

Comment: You may want to clarify that the empty set is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Must the answer be a list of the entries, can it be a bitmask with the ith bit set iff item[i] is in the set?

Comment: @harold Yes, the bitmask sounds fine to me.

Comment: @Arnauld I think returning all solutions should be fine. I agree it would be good to clarify on the empty set, I meant to do that when writing the question but forgot.

Comment: May we assume the entries are distinct?

Comment: @xnor Yes, will add that.

Comment: What is the maximum value for \$d\$?

Comment: @qwr I guess you are asking because harold's answer only handles \$d\leq 32\$? I think that's alright, certainly it's larger than any of my test cases. Many of the other solutions use brute force and would never finish if \$d=32\$. Plus it's nice for people to have fun and it doesn't seem like all that many people golf assembly language.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒPḊ^/ÞḢ
```

A monadic Link accepting the list of distinct integers representing the vectors which yields a subset representing the linear dependence. (May be employed as a dyadic Link also accepting the number of dimensions on the right.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opICHO7ri9A/Pe7hj0f///6MNjXUUDE10FIyA2BjINjYFYjMdBTPj2P9mAA)**

#### How?

```
ŒPḊ^/ÞḢ - Link: list of distinct integers   e.g. [1,3,4,7]
ŒP      - power-set                              [[],[1],[3],[4],[7],[1,3],[1,4],[1,7],[3,4],[3,7],[4,7],[1,3,4],[1,3,7],[1,4,7],[3,4,7],[1,3,4,7]],[3,4,7],[1,3,4,7]]
  Ḋ     - dequeue                                [[1],[3],[4],[7],[1,3],[1,4],[1,7],[3,4],[3,7],[4,7],[1,3,4],[1,3,7],[1,4,7],[3,4,7],[1,3,4,7]],[3,4,7],[1,3,4,7]]
     Þ  - sort by:
    /   -   reduce by:
   ^    -     XOR                              ( [1,3,4,7,2,5,6,7,4,3,6,5,2,0,1] )
        - }                                      [[3,4,7],[1],[1,3,4,7],[1,3],[1,4,7],[3],[4,7],[4],[3,7],[1,4],[1,3,7],[1,7],[1,3,4],7,[3,4]]
      Ḣ - head                                   [3,4,7]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 39 bytes

```perl6
{first {![+^] $_},.combinations(1..$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/bCsIwEETf/YoViiiGYu6Klx8ptVSxULCttH0ppd8eJwS8PizJzp6ZTR639m5cNdCioKMbi7LtehrnyfqcUpRNLL421aWs875s6m7J4zjKVpPr8oEKOnCSpMie9rMgJJKRZmQY7Rhxlb50xWgLZYMSfxMOC7eMBGekYNQ4tX0jaG3wA5Qe0D@A9JkIQEncpefwCCM/GL8bSQIzgSyFXiPLiK9F4QMe5BhKEULcEw)

Returns the first combination of the input that is zero when reduced XOR. I wish `{![+^] $_}` could be changed to `!*.&[+^]`.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
hxFDty
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6PCzaWk8v//aEMdBXMdBQsdBUNTHQVjSx0FUyBtah4LAA)

To explain, back to front:

- `y` generates all subsets of the input.
- `t` (tail) removes the first, empty subset.
- `D` means order by the following function:
- `F` means reduce on:
- `x` is the xor function.
- `h` (head) takes the first element of the sorted list.

The lists that xor to 0 will be sorted to the front.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 79 bytes

```hs
import Data.Bits
p[a]=[[a]]
p(a:b)=map(a:)(p b)++p b
filter((1>).foldl xor 0).p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcaxDsIgEADQna@4wQHShljdSHAwLn4DYbjGEokHXOgN/j3W5eW9cf9sRGPkwq0LPFDQ3rPsigNGHw6iYo1uNb7gP0YzrGaaDlXyKZNsXevlZmxq9CL4tg5nY3kUzNVzz1VOKSzzZb6Cc/CsEscP)

Defines the power set (ignoring the empty set) as `p`, then our solution is:

```hs
filter((1>).foldl xor 0).p
```

Or in english:

> Get the power set and then select all the members whose xor sum is less than 1 (i.e. zero).

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
æ¦.Δ.»^>
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJDy/TOTdE7tDvO7v//aENjHQVDEx0FIyA2BrKNTYHYTEfBzDgWAA)**

#### How?

```
æ¦.Δ.»^> - implicitly take input
æ        - power-set
 ¦       - tail
  .Δ     - keep first which is 1 under:
    .»   -   reduce by:
      ^  -     XOR
       > -   increment
         - implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 74 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,s=[],v=0:s*(v<1)or a and(f(n:=a[1:],s+a[:1],v^a[0])or f(n,s,v))
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpRCsIwEESvks@N7kfjapFgThIibKnFQk1DEgOePm4HHgwzL/3qe490T7n3xW38mWZWjMX5gM0NtpygPYzes5I5zrBAtI69sQHLmb01oj3ZD@FQ5MSCTeue8hqryK/GG6wxfStoSfeGUJkrqotA0ukmjKhGCn8)**

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>84 60</s>  58 bytes

[Ignores \$d\$](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12442/58563). Returns \$0\$ if there's no solution.

```javascript
f=([v,...a],x,o=[])=>x<1?o:v?f(a,x,o)||f(a,x^v,[...o,v]):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BDoIwEEX3nqJLmoyEthSUiByE1ISgGA2hRkzDgrvjL7gTFk2n7ftvps/KVX39frw@@85eb9PU5EHpKAzDytBANi8Nz8/DSRQ2c0UTVP6Sj@NcXRyVIC05w7Noqm3X2/YWtvYeNEEpiCliMbHUcL77f5TEEmIiAhatEMjqmTgCilcAmA9LXshtREAiUnRDxxgqjV1vTJQuRiSUJ/UWqXw7KLEUauUDGDRRa7Cfz/8WkIQ9xlnDnsj1GZZv@4QApeRPO30B)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                        // f is a recursive function taking:
  [v,                        //   v   = next value from the input set
      ...a],                 //   a[] = array of remaining values
  x,                         //   x   = 'XOR total', initially undefined
  o = []                     //   o[] = output subset
) =>                         //
  x < 1 ?                    // if x is defined and equal to 0:
    o                        //   success: return o[]
  :                          // else:
    v ?                      //   if v is defined:
      f(a, x, o) ||          //     try a recursive call where v is ignored
      f(a, x ^ v, [...o, v]) //     try a recursive call where v is used
    :                        //   else:
      0                      //     failed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
f=->a{(1..a.size).map{|x|a.combination(x).map{|x|return x if x.reduce(:^)<1}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9dC4IwFIbv@xW7nLBG@9KK6o9EwbQJglmsBCv97fYuI7C6GNvO@5znbL5Ob32fr6cb@6CCc8svxd1F/GjPj7ZpLc9Ox7So7LU4VbT51L271r4iDSly0nDvDnXm6HIfrUTXdf2Z5jyzZUm3ghHFiGYk2UXRZFSXjMSMiBmI2ThEh3mFC@R6nEE1H7qE/JsKtIoEeozQEBjs5nd6MngAqwCZP5AKfoiwFM4qsHhUrL648JbwH@QSTo27gTOWP0OHjwVYAFDyLeuf)

:^)

Probably golfable.

Comment: [74 bytes: replaced the return with a find/compact structure, and then cheesed out the reduce with an eval.](https://tio.run/##bY/JDoIwFEX3fkWXrSkNbSlo4vAhBJOKkpAAEqfgwLfjrbhBWDQd7nnnvZ5v@0fXZWtvY1@USiGsuOTPIxOlrV/v5m1Feir3eWWv@amiDRNZXh1ccLzbgjbz7Y6tZNt6cZ2w2E/arqaZSG1R0FhyojkJOIkSxmaDd8VJyIn0QfjDEBXmGy6RB8MMqkVfJdVkKlEqI@jRIoDAYDfj7lHvAawdZCYg7fwQYWmctWMxVKj/ODeL@w9yBWeAu4EzVKOm/cccLAFo9ZN1Hw "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 36 bytes

```
0-.~1{ ::0[:(#~0=XOR/"1)]#~2#:@i.@^#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@xigIxEIZ7n@LDLVbhsmYyya4bEATBShCsBNFGTu6uuQc42Fffm8XCJhZThO/L/PP/jPOmfrDJ1HzgyTauYXc67EfvmkH@yNlf8qIa/OZ8PK3msrxWQ6jy9rvZ3qpxOWP2ef/65YGgRLrns3bO1S8SaBGP@gJVktEeiQUYWU8fJbzDkpCOIMSeJKRyfjetSag56Y2jlkCIqKJmtrRa0uwWq5MIa6In9bShmDi1MlN61Mrr@A8)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
f[d_,l_]:=NullSpace[IntegerDigits[#,2,d]&/@l,Modulus->2][[1]]
```

This gives a bitmask (well a list of zeros and ones) of which elements of the list are in the set, as was allowed by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
Select[Rest@Subsets@#,BitXor@@#==0&]&
```

Returns the list of solutions or an empty list if no solutions exist.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NC8IgGMfvfQphsJOHqXOrgyB9gmiXQDys4WrQCjY7RZ/d/ubo5SD6/F9@j2Prz25s/dC1IfSqcRfXebN3s9fN/Tg7P@uMbgd/uE1aZ0oVuc3DSe2m4epNbzJr89XJPBglgpKSkvppl5lTUlHCCjhFEpGQb3EDvUwaKuuUYvxPZYiyGhigShQkbvml16mHkIim/DFF5KCII/AWMYOllVj8uCv@DzoHo8Qswaj4B54@GkMMhuCpHF4)

Answer (score 1):

## x86 machine code, 27 bytes

```
578B7C240831C04031D231C90FA3C8730333148F67E2F575EE5FC3
```

Iterating through bit masks and XORing together the items as selected by the mask. In MASM-format assembly:

```
_lindep PROC
    push edi
    mov edi, [esp + 8]
    xor eax, eax
_loop:
    inc eax
    xor edx, edx
    xor ecx, ecx
_inner:
    bt eax, ecx
    jnc _skip
    xor edx, [edi + 4 * ecx]
_skip:
    byte 67h
    loop _inner
    jnz _loop
    pop edi
    ret
_lindep ENDP
```

It's a cdecl function, not stdcall.

There is an odd requirement: the input array must be padded to 65536 items long, but only 32 items are actually used. That's because I used a 16-bit `loop` and relied it on it wrapping from 0 to 65535, The padding has to exist in order to make the program not die with an access violation.

Using `loop` this way, in addition to gaining the benefit from it being small, means the zero flag is not modified between the `xor` and the `jnz` of the outer loop. Almost any other construct would need an extra instruction just to re-test whether `edx` is zero, except using `lea` to increment the loop counter and `bt ecx, 5` to stop when it hits 32, which is bigger.

Driver program in case you want to run it:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" int lindep(int* vecs, int d);
int vecs[65536] = { 1, 3, 4, 7 };
int main()
{
    std::cout << lindep(vecs, 3) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: why are only 32 items used? and the requirement to pad the input array is stretching the I/O rules too far IMO.

Comment: @qwr the bitmask only has 32 bits in it so more than that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
ＩΦＥＸ²ＬθΦθ﹪÷ιＸ²μ²∧ι⬤↨⌈θ²¬﹪Σ÷ιＸ²μ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzBCsIwEER/ZY8bWA@tlCqeqiIIVgoeSw@hCTaQJrZNq38fEyje3MPssjPz2o6PreXa@2pUxuGJTw4vSjs5YslfWNl3uFKCmzRP1@HAGMHqDwSlFbO2eDXurBYlJCqCX6WP2ZRFLYyIVqE1HvkkA/qj@rkPuJgguFuHK@sR3n95KzDOwfu6Tghygh1BkhFs9wRZ2FneNH6z6C8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs all matches. Explanation:

```
    ²                               Literal 2
   Ｘ                                Raised to power
      θ                             Input array
     Ｌ                              Length
  Ｅ                                 Map over implicit range
        θ                           Input array
       Φ                            Filtered where nonzero
           ι                        Outer index
          ÷                         Integer divide by
             ²                      Literal 2
            Ｘ                       Raised to power
              μ                     Inner index
         ﹪                          Modulo
               ²                    Literal 2
 Φ                                  Filter powerset where
                 ι                  Current subset (is not empty)
                ∧                   Logical And
                     θ              Input array
                    ⌈               Maximum
                   ↨                Convert to base
                      ²             Literal 2
                  ⬤                 Has all values where
                           ι        Current powerset
                          ÷         Vectorised integer divide by
                             ²      Literal 2
                            Ｘ       Raised to power
                              μ     Inner index
                         Σ          Sum
                        ﹪           Modulo
                               ²    Literal 2
                       ¬            Is zero
Ｉ                                   Cast to string
                                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 16 bytes

```
peR@{{$$}r[n!}fe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/IDXIobpaRaW2KDpPsTYNKGKiUG1ooGBoqGBkqmBkoWBioGBqqWBmVAsA)

Takes arguments as `d {1 2 3 4...}`

```
pe      # Read vals and push to stack
R@      # Generate all subsets
{
 {$$}r[ # Reduce by xor
 n!     # Boolean not
}fe     # Find first element
```